# Twitter Cards : How to use only 2 images in twitter gallery card?

Tags: meta, twitter-card

Here are the meta tags for twitter cards :

```
  <meta name="twitter:card" content="gallery">
  <meta name="twitter:site" content="@site_creator">
  <meta name="twitter:creator" content="@site_creator">
  <meta name="twitter:title" content="Top 10 Things Ever">
  <meta name="twitter:description" content="Up than 200 characters.">
  <meta name="twitter:image0:src" content="http://placekitten.com/200/200">
  <meta name="twitter:image1:src" content="http://placekitten.com/300/300">
  <meta name="twitter:image2:src" content="http://placekitten.com/350/350">
  <meta name="twitter:image3:src" content="http://placekitten.com/150/150">
  <meta name="twitter:domain" content="YourDomain.com">
  <meta name="twitter:app:name:iphone" content="Vine">
  <meta name="twitter:app:name:ipad" content="Vine">
  <meta name="twitter:app:name:googleplay" content="Vine">
  <meta name="twitter:app:url:iphone" content="vine://v/93582sxlkjf">
  <meta name="twitter:app:url:ipad" content="vine://v/93582sxlkjf">
  <meta name="twitter:app:url:googleplay" content="http://vine.co/v/93582sxlkjf">
  <meta name="twitter:app:id:iphone" content="id592447445">
  <meta name="twitter:app:id:ipad" content="id432984038404">
  <meta name="twitter:app:id:googleplay" content="co.vine.android">>
```

If I do not place following meta tags , gallery card does not work.

```
<meta name="twitter:image2:src" content="http://placekitten.com/350/350">
<meta name="twitter:image3:src" content="http://placekitten.com/150/150">
```

I need to place two images only, Can you please help me to solve this ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to fake it out by providing place holders with either an empty content link (content="") or else linking to images that are really tiny (like 1x1 pixel or something)?

Comment: Yes.. it still shows 4 images with blank stuff while playing slideshow

Comment: I personally have found the twitter cards to be quite inflexible and unforgiving. I would ask on the twitter developer forum and see if anyone there can help. Do you have an option to post a tweet through the API or are the cards your only option? I think that the "POST statuses/update" API method supports adding media (images), and I believe that you can upload a variable number of images <= 4. But it's a lot more complicated than the card approach. Sorry I couldn't help more. I have been finding programming with Twitter pretty frustrating myself. Good luck!

Comment: Indeed.. Twitter cards are too frustrating .. But I have to use twitter cards only.. Yes twitter  "POST statuses/updateWithMedia" API method supports adding media .. But I need to use twitter cards only.. Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

[Gallery Card](https://dev.twitter.com/cards/types/gallery) was deprecated on July 3, 2015 and has been mapped to the [Summary Card with Large Image](https://dev.twitter.com/cards/types/summary-large-image).